# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/arch/core/internal/SafeIterableMap.class

Tags: android

While trying to build my app, Android Studio throws the below exception:

> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/arch/core/internal/SafeIterableMap.class

App Gradle

compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

```
compile "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"

compile "com.android.support:multidex:$rootProject.multidexVersion"

compile("android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.androidRoomVersion") 

annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.androidRoomVersion"

compile "com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:$rootProject.firebaseJobDispatcherVersion"

compile("org.simpleframework:simple-xml:$rootProject.simpleXmlVersion") {
    exclude module: 'stax'
    exclude module: 'stax-api'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
}
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

Project  Gradle

```
 compileSdkVersion       =   26
buildToolsVersion       =   '26.0.2'
minSdkVersion           =   19
targetSdkVersion        =   26


 supportLibraryVersion           =     '27.0.2'
playServicesVersion             =     '9.8.0'
androidRoomVersion              =     '1.0.0-alpha2'
okHttpVersion                   =     '3.8.1'
gsonVersion                     =     '2.6.2'
firebaseJobDispatcherVersion    =     '0.8.5'
multidexVersion                 =     '1.0.1'
simpleXmlVersion                =     '2.7.+'
butterknifeVersion              =     '8.7.0'
facebookStethoVersion           =     '1.5.0'
timberVersion                   =     '4.6.0'
tutoshowcaseVersion             =     '1.0.1'
zxingScannerVersion             =     '1.9.8'
glideVersion                    =     '3.7.0'
exoplayerVersion                =     'r2.4.0'
```

Comment: show us your full `build.gradle` files at least

Comment: i shared gradle file can u check.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue.

[image]

I Understood that it's because of the duplicate dependency and the solution is to exclude the particular module which makes the duplicate. To identify that I ran the build with info.

Before running the build I added **android.enableBuildCache=false** attribute in gradle.properties to avoid path name from the cache.

[image]

Searched usage of SafeIterableMap$ListIterator.class and found that there are two jars it adds SafeIterableMap$ListIterator.class.

I got like this.

[image]

From that, I have got the clear understanding of what to exclude and where to keep exclude. Added exclude as below and ran the build.

[image]

That fixes my issue.